# How do I pass state from a parent (wrapper component) to its children with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a parent component which loads some data from the backend in the `componentWillMount` method. This comes from a single config endpoint which should only be called once. What I'd like to do load the data into his parent component and then wrap a number of child components with this state. To contextualize this the parent component is a navbar and a footer for a dashboard, the children would be views within this dashboard, i.e. the dashboard page content. React-Router's documentation explains that `{this.props.children}` is the preferred method for handling this but doesn't seem to explain how to pass state down to the children. How do I go about doing this?

Also it might be worth illustrating my routes:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' onEnter={redirectWww} />
    <Route
        path='/dashboard'
        component={DashboardContainerWrapper}
        onEnter={requireAuth}>
        <Route path='/dashboard/' component={DashboardIndex}/>
        <Route path='/dashboard/some/view' component={DashboardSomeView}/>
    </Route>
 </Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually just had to do something similar today. What I did was I used React.cloneElement to inject the parent components state into the child components. In your render method

```
{React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) =>
  React.cloneElement(child, {...this.state})
)}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. To clarify I want to copy the state of the parent into the child as the child's state. What I may have to do instead is break this up into two endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I can pass state and function from parent to children just like:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' onEnter={redirectWww} />
    <Route
        path='/dashboard'
        component={() => (
        <DashboardContainerWrapper browserHistory={browserHistory} /> )}
        onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route path='/dashboard/' component={DashboardIndex}/>
        <Route path='/dashboard/some/view' component={DashboardSomeView}/>
    </Route>
 </Router>
```